# wx.TextCtrl don't wrap on OSX wxpython

Tags: python, windows, macos, wxpython, wx.textctrl

I have a wx.TextCtrl window which I have a couple of bugs in, 1 bug in windows, 1 bug in OSX.

Bug 1: I don't want to wrap the text in the wx.TextCtrl window, but must me multiline, this works fine in Windows, but not in OSX.

Bug 2: When adding text to the wx.TextCtrl window it does not auto scroll in Windows, but works fine in OSX. As the text gets entered the scroll bar stays at the top of the window, you can manually drag the scroll bar down to the bottom to see the newly entered text, but on OSX this happens automatically.

```
self.running_log1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.running1, -1, pos=(5, 5), size=(875,605),
                               style = wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY | wx.HSCROLL | wx.TE_DONTWRAP)
```

Im on OSX 10.9.2, Windows 7, Python 2.7.6, wxpython 3.

Comment: Please add relevant language tags where applicable (Python), and OS tags too when crucial (OSX is the only place where the bug occurs).

Comment: No problem. I only edited the tags.